# Failure trying to write tests using jenkins-test-harness

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to write tests for my Job DSL code using jenkins-test-harness. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/model/RootAction
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.model.RootAction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 38 more
```

I would expect that this is caused by a dependency issue in my pom.xml, but I did add the Jenkins war to the list of dependencies (Note: I'm new to maven, so I may just be missing something.):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
  <groupId>org.jenkins-ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>jenkins</artifactId>
  <version>1.37</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mysimpletest</groupId>
<artifactId>mysimpletest</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>mysimpletest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-war</artifactId>
    <version>2.110</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-test-harness</artifactId>
    <version>2.34</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>org.jenkins-ci</id>
    <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Just to be sure: You simply missed the closing "</project>" at copy paste from your pom?

Comment: Indeed, that was a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1):

To include the war file is not the right way, if you like to test something. Just think about how should the correct lib be found inside that folders...

Just add the concrete dependency for that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.110</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also why you added the parent? My suggestion: Just only include stuff, that you really need...

Comment: I'm afraid my lack of familiarity with Maven was the problem. Thanks for the suggestion, this indeed seems to fix the problem (on to the next!). I will aware the bounty once I can do so...